# R: how to extract column in multiple csv and then write multiple csv in one folder

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have a folder (folder 1) containing multiple csv: "x.csv", "y.csv", "z.csv"...
I want to extract the 3rd column of each file and then write new csv files in a new folder (folder 2). Hence, folder 2 must contain "x.csv", "y.csv", "z.csv"...(but with just the 3rd column).

I tried this:

```
dfiles <- list.files(pattern =".csv") #if you want to read all the files in working directory
lst2 <- lapply(dfiles, function(x) (read.csv(x, header=FALSE)[,3]))
```

But I got this error:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(read.csv(x, header = FALSE), , 3) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Moreover, I don't know how to write multiple csv.

However, if I do this with one file, it works properly, despite the output is in the same folder:

```
essai <-read.csv("x.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")[,3]
write.csv (essai, file = "x.csv")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so here's how I would do it. There may be a nicer and more efficient way but it should still work pretty well.

```
setwd("~/stackexchange") #set your main folder. Best way to do this is actually the here() package. But that's another topic.


library(tools) #for file extension tinkering
folder1 <- "folder1" #your original folder
folder2 <- "folder2" #your new folder

#I setup a function and loop over it with lapply.
write_to <- function(file.name){
file.name <-  paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file.name)), ".csv")
essai <-read.csv(paste(folder1, file.name, sep = "/"), header = FALSE, sep = ",")[,3]
write.csv(essai, file = paste(folder2, file.name, sep="/")) 
}


# get file names from folder 1
dfiles <- list.files(path=folder1, pattern ="*.csv") #if you want to read all the csv files in folder1 directory

lapply(X = paste(folder1, dfiles, sep="/"), write_to)
```

Have fun! 
Btw: if you have many files, you could use `data.table::fread` and `data.table::fwrite` which improves csv reading/writing speed by a lot.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why but the read.csv seems not work well when I use it in the function you propose (or lapply below). And I the get the error message with the "undefined columns selected"...

Comment: I think that [Ronak's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61866920/9717643) answer below might be helpful then. Have you checked whether all your csv files have indeed a 3rd column?

Comment: ok. Without knowing the file structure, I am not sure I can be of much further help. I tried it with 2 random csv files on my machine and it worked fine. Two suggestions (1) try it with 1-2 random csv files and see if it works. (2) Do you have to skip some variables, e.g. are your column names on row1?

Comment: I finally soved the problem and manage to do it with your script. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from the error message it seems that some of the csv files have less than 3 columns. Check if you are reading the correct files and if all of them are supposed to have 3 columns at least.

Once you do that you can use the below code, to read the csv file, select the 3rd column and write the csv file in `'folder2'`.

```
lapply(dfiles, function(x) {
   df <- read.csv(x, header = FALSE)
   write.csv(subset(df, select = 3), paste0('folder2/', x), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it could work but I still have the error message. I'm reading the correct files and all of them have 3 columns... To better understand the problem, I kept just my first file in the folder to see what happen. First, I did things separately: read.csv (I got a df with 3 columns) then write.csv with the subset (and I got what I wanted). Then I tried with the lapply, and I got the error message... and it kind of drives me crazy because I d'on't understand why...

Comment: @AdeLac74 Can you run `sapply(dfiles, function(x) nrow(read.csv(x, header = FALSE)))` and see number of rows. Is there any value less than 3?

Comment: When I do this, I get just the number of row. I think something get wrong with the read.csv function. If I do this (still with my folder containing just the first file):  `df <-lapply(dfiles, function(x) {
  read.csv(x, header = FALSE)
})` I get a list with 1df, with just 1 variable.

Comment: Sorry, we need to check number of columns. Do `sapply(dfiles, function(x) ncol(read.csv(x, header = FALSE)))` instead and check if there is any data which is less than 3. What is output of `which(sapply(dfiles, function(x) ncol(read.csv(x, header = FALSE))) <= 2)` ?

Comment: Ok thanks; there is only one column and the output of the second line is that:`01A_CHANI_lab.csv 
                1 `(that is, the name of my file, and, obviously, the number of my file)

Comment: ok...so that is the file with 1 column, right? What do you want to do with that file?

Comment: No the file contain 3 columns and if I do this `df <-read.csv("01A_CHANI_lab.csv", header = FALSE)`, I get a df with 3 columns. So I don't understand why it is not the case when I do it with lapply

Comment: I see..but what is output of `which(sapply(dfiles, function(x) ncol(read.csv(x, header = FALSE))) <= 2)` ?

Comment: the output is the name of my file and the number of the file (just below). `01A_CHANI_lab.csv   01C_HUFCE_lab.csv   02A_ALBGU_lab.csv   02C_VENLA_lab.csv   03A_FISCA_lab.csv   03C_FISHA_lab.csv   04A_MORPI_lab.csv 
                  1                   2                   3                   4                   5                   6                   7` (the presentation is not like here; the number is just below the file)

Comment: yes, so it means these files have number of columns less than 3, right? Did you check them?

Comment: Yes I checked, and as I told you, these files all have 3 columns. If I do the process file by file like `df <-read.csv("01A_CHANI_lab.csv", header = FALSE)`, I get a df with 3 column.  But if I do the same thing with lapply, it seems that the file has just one column. That is the point that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

For the "write" portion of this question, I had some luck using map2() in purrr. I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution but here it goes:

```
listofessais # this is your .csv files together as a named list of tbls
map2(listofessais, names(listofessais), ~write_csv(.x, glue("FilePath/{.y}.csv"))
```

That should give you all your .csv files exported in that folder, and named with the same names they were given in the list.